# ProjectReference being converted to a Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Our team has a solution with two class libraries (A, B).

- B has a "Project Reference" to A.
- A is published to an internal NuGet server.
- B also has a dependency on a class library C (internal; but exists in a different repo, solution).
- C is published to the same internal NuGet server.
- C also has a dependency on A.

We are experiencing that at some point during the development process, the B.csproj is modified and the ProjectReference to A is replaced with a Reference to an older version of A that exists in the packages folder (the version of A that C depends on).

I believe we have come across a bug in how Nuget and/or Visual Studio resolve version conflicts, but first wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions before reporting it.

Comment: If A is being published as a NuGet package, why cannot B depend on the NuGet package A rather than the project A?

Comment: It could - but it feels awkward (IMO) for them to be in the same solution yet have to use NuGet to make changes in A available to B.  If we were to go down this path, I would move A into a different VS solution.  My preference would be to keep A and B in the same solution.

Comment: Doesn't the source control history of B shows when was it changed and by who?

Comment: Yes. But the developer is not making the change intentionally.  We have talked about a commit hook to prevent the change.  But I still would like to identify the root cause.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to take a decision on the true/ideal 'separate-ness' of the projects and let that drive where they sit (solution/NuGet/etc). Don't be afraid to duplicate code, too - "shared libraries" which have no need to be shared are the source of much pain.

Comment: I am comfortable with the structure of the libraries and the dependency tree.  I just believe it to be a bug for Nuget/VS to modify the reference type within the csproj file.  At this point, we will proceed with evaluating writing a commit hook for GIT.